# Getting null value of Global variable in java class?

Tags: java

Here is my Code:

```
public class ServerCall {

    Context context;
    public int cartCount;

    public ServerCall(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public Integer addCartItem(RequestObject requestObject) {

        new AddToCartList().execute(requestObject);

        Log.d("count",String.valueOf(cartCount));

        return cartCount;

    }


   public class AddToCartList extends AsyncTask<RequestObject, Void, JSONObject> {


        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(RequestObject... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0], ServiceHandler.POST);

            //  List<Products> result = new ArrayList<Products>();

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            JSONObject product = new JSONObject();


            if (jsonStr != null) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    product = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rsBody");


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return product;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {

                if (result != null) {
                    String status = result.getString("status");
                    int totalCartItem = result.getInt("totalCartItem");
                    /* cartHelper = new CartHelper();
                    cartHelper.setStatus(status);
                    cartHelper.setTotalCartItem(totalCartItem);*/
                    cartCount=totalCartItem;

                    Log.d("status",status);
                    Log.d("totalCartItem",String.valueOf(cartCount));
                    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return;

        }
    }
}
```

We didn't get value of global variable `cartCount` which I set inside `AddToCartList` class and try to get its value from `addCartItem()` function from where `AddToCartList` is called but we get null value.

Comment: Because the `AsyncTask` runs, well, asynchronously! Your `log` statement happens **immediately** after `execute()`. The `doInBackground` method completely sometime **after** that.

Comment: you can use `yourTask.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` to wait 1 second for the end of your task and log after this

Comment: You can't get the `cartCount` before it is calculated so you task is not inherently concurrent. I.e. the best solution is to not attempt to run it in the background as your calling thread would just have to wait for the result anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem in your solution is the fact that you're trying to edit `ServerCall` variable from an Inner class, this would work only if cartCount is static, and I suggest you wait for your task to be finished as some people have already mentioned, using the [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method `new AddToCartList().execute().get()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, ServerCall and AddToCartList are not the same class, so you must first get a reference to the servercall in addtocartlit, then reference the cartCount using your reference to the servercall instance, like call.cartCount, instead of cartcount, unless its an inner class which it does not appear to be.

Secondly, you must save a reference to the addtocartlist asynctask inside addCartItem()  ,then call its .get() method after starting it, this will ensure it finishes before you try to log the new value.